# react nextjs export env variable to client

Tags: reactjs, next.js, global

I have a next.js react application which I build into a docker container and deploy on different servers. Each server has slightly different settings which I setup with environment variables. So far so good.

Now I want to have one of these configuration variables be accessible on the client side javascript. If I use NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_VAR it arrives at the client side but the value is set at build time and is not useful in my case.

Seems that getServerSideProps is a possibility. However this turns out to be very involved in my case. The variable I want to configure is a prefix to put on every `<TITLE>` tag in every page. So I should define the function getServerSideProps on every page.

Since the server knows the correct value it is only a matter of putting that value somewhere in the HTML code sent to the client... I would be able to do this in a custom react environment but next.js is hiding me that level.

Comment: Since you are trying to write page title, have you considered using https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/head?

Comment: You might also consider adding a middleware